# Nginx reverse-proxy for python app using docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi i am trying to create a python app and redis with nginx reverse-proxy but when i run the docker-compose file it runs all the container but when I go to localhost:90 it shows nginx page, not the page defined in python file. I was following this tutorial [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-nginx-reverse-proxy-with-flask-and-docker-66854e940176)

Docker file:

```
FROM python:3
RUN pip install flask
```

Python file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# to connect redis 
# use host "redis_app"
# use port "6379"
# use password "add_password_here"

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello NGINX reverse proxy'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

Docker-compose-file

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        container_name: nginx_reverseproxy
        depends_on:
            - flask
        volumes:
            - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
        networks:
            - docker-network
        ports:
            - 90:80
    flask:
        build:
            context: ./
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        image: flask:v1
        container_name: flask_webapp
        volumes:
            - ./:/flask_code/
        environment:
            - FLASK_APP=/flask_code/main.py
        command: python /flask_code/main.py
        networks:
            docker-network:
                aliases:
                    - flask_webapp
        ports:
            - 8080:5000
        depends_on:
                - redis
    redis:
        image: redis
networks:
    docker-network:
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen 90;
    server_name localhost;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask_webapp:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing you need to create bridge network. lets say the network name is `my_project_network`.

```
docker network create --driver=bridge my_project_network
```

---

Now we will create python app.

index.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

# to connect redis 
# use host "redis_app"
# use port "6379"
# use password "add_password_here"

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello NGINX reverse proxy'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

---

We will use flask so we need to install it. we can do it by create `requirements.txt` file and use `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` to install it.

requirements.txt

```
flask==1.1.2
```

---

Now will create `Dockerfile` for python app.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir -p /my_project

WORKDIR /my_project

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "./index.py"]
```

---

Now will create `nginx` configuration file.

default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://flask_app:5000/;
        proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
    }
}
```

---

Now will create `docker-compose` file.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  nginx_app:
    image: nginx:latest
    depends_on:
      - flask_app
    volumes:
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    networks:
      - my_project_network

  flask_app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5000
    depends_on:
      - redis_app
    networks:
      - my_project_network

  redis_app:
    image: redis:latest
    command: redis-server --requirepass add_password_here
    expose:
      - 6379
    networks:
      - my_project_network

networks:
  my_project_network:
    external: true
```

---

Now we done all files. so we will run docker compose.

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

To stop it just use

```
docker-compose stop
```

---

Results

[image]

---

NOTE: You can replace port `8080` with any port you need.

---

NOTE: I created `my_project_network` to can connect service in docker compose each other. but I can do it with out `my_project_network`. but I prefer to use `my_project_network` to connect any service from anther docker compose to this docker compose services.

Lets say we have. `./anther_project/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  flask_app_v2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 5001:5001
    networks:
      - my_project_network

networks:
  my_project_network:
    external: true
```

The `flask_app_v2` can connect to `redis_app` because they are all in the same network
.

---

Comment: this helped me to setup a test flask applicztion setup. thank you